# Google App script and local database connectivity

Tags: google-apps-script

I have mysql server installed on my machine. I would like to connect to the same local mysql instance using Google app script's jdbc service. I am getting connection failed error. So, I would like to confirm:
1. is it possible to connect to mysql instance running on private machine(laptop) using jdbc service.
2. If not is it always mandatory to connect to public IP. What is the alternative to connect to mysql instance running on private machine.

Comment: Are your sure your DB is visible from outside your network?

Comment: when I do netstat it shows
 TCP    127.0.0.1:3306         user-PC:50259          ESTABLISHED

Comment: Can you please share how can i make DB visible outside network.

Comment: I [found this site](http://www.rainbowspuppiessunshine.com/tools/dbtest/) but I recommend that you change your password immediately after using it.

Answer (score 1):

This definitely works, but you need to permit Google's machines to connect to your machine.  That means opening a hole in your firewall, possibly setting up port forwarding on your router, etc.

There is an alternative to poking a hole in your security arrangement, it is called Secure Data Connector, and it lets your machine initiate the connection to Google - https://developers.google.com/secure-data-connector/

Unfortunately, I don't believe that SDC supports JDBC yet (I believe it only supports HTTP based communication).

(P.S. One very simple work around is to mirror your local database to some kind of cloud service, and then permit access to that replica from Google).

Comment: if you have a local webserver, you can build a page to perform mysql queries and SDC can query that...